# replace characters in string before file extension

Tags: powershell

I've got a variable, with the following string values:

```
PS C:\> $sql.physicalname
I:\Data\Data1.mdf
I:\Data\Data2.ndf
I:\Data\Data3.ndf
I:\Data\Data4.ndf
I:\Data\Data5.ndf
I:\Data\Data6.ndf
I:\Data\Data7.ndf
I:\Data\Data8.ndf
I:\Data\Data9.ndf
I:\Data\log.ldf
```

What I want is to replace/trim the strings so that only the .mdf/.ndf/.ldf extensions remain:

```
.mdf
.ndf
.ndf
.ndf
.ndf
.ndf
.ndf
.ndf
.ndf
.ldf
```

I tried using the `-replace` parameter with the `*` wildcard, but I cant wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is a regular expression you pass to `-replace`, try it e.g. with

```
-replace ".*\.", "."
```

A better and more robust way would be to use something like that

```
$sql.physicalname | % { [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_) }
```

Comment: Works like a charm, still cant figure out why your code is working though. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The '.' in a regular expression essentially matches any character and the '*' means 0 or more occurrences. If you want to match the '.' itself one has to escape it with a backslash therefore '.*\.' means match all characters from the beginning of the string until the first '.' is encountered - the '.' included. Following a link to MSDN with more info about the .NET regex https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension()`